# How to import a ArrayList from another file?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working in Netbeans on a project and have a problem with importing `ArrayList`.

This is my `main` java file where I create an `ArrayList`. Basically, when I run the program, it pops up a window, which contains a text field (`txfnamn`) and a button (`btnFortsatt`). When I press the button, I want to save the text entered in the field in the ArrayList. So I did this:

(`GlosLista` is a Java file with my instance method and constructor.)

//Create a new ArrayList

`public static List<GlosLista> gloslista = new ArrayList<GlosLista>();`

//Button Action

```
private void btnFortsattActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    String text = txfSkapaNamn.getText();
    gloslista.add(new GlosLista(text));private void
```

}

Then there is another java file and here I want to import the `ArrayList` and show it on a JList:

```
public static void Display() {

List<GlosLista> lista = new ArrayList<GlosLista>(gloslista);
DefaultListModel dm = new DefaultListModel();
dm.clear();
for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
    dm.addElement(lista.get(i));
}
```

The problem is that the program does not show the list.

Comment: Can you post more code of the two classes ?

Comment: `List lista = Main.gloslista;`?

Comment: Display needs to take a parameter with the same type, so public static void Display(List<GlosLista> gloslist).  Then when you call Display, you pass the list like this:  Display(gloslista).

Comment: Can you add some other pieces of code?? So we can understand your problems and help you!

Comment: Sure! Let me know if you want more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `main` java file is called `Main` then just:

```
public static void Display()
{
  DefaultListModel dm = new DefaultListModel();
  for( GlosLista gl : Main.gloslista )
  {
    dm.addElement( gl );
  }
}
```